# Xcode: Is it possible to add gesture recognizers to objects like buttons, images etc

Tags: iphone, xcode, addition, uigesturerecognizer

I was wondering if it is possible to add gesture recognizers to objects like buttons, images etc.

I have used this code to create a gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(foundTap:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
```

and than when I try to add the gesture I use this code:

```
[button addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Problem is that it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works great for me on a UIButton, and overrides the normal action of the button.

Can you be more specific about "doesn't work"?  You mean it gives an error?  Or you see no callback?

If the latter, how did you declare the method 'foundTap:' ?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I only tested it on a UILabel and a UIImage. Figured out that "User Interaction Enabled" wasn't enabled. But thank you :)